# is coordinate descent algorithm derivative free

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I was going through a tutorial on coordinate descent algorithm available on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent.

The tutorial begins with "Coordinate descent is a derivative-free optimization algorithm."

However, in the pseudo code, there comes a derivative term in the weight update equation (see figure).

[image]

What's the catch? Is there a different interpretation to "derivative free"?

Answer (score 5):

Coordinate descent proceeds by iteratively finding the minima of the one variable functions formed by fixing the values of all but one coordinate. 
 The derivative here is just a convenient way to find the minimum of those functions, but you can use another method if derivatives are not available.

You can use any method to find these minima in a coordinate descent algorithm.  If you don't have derivatives available, you can use a grid search, and if you have more than just the first you can use Newton's method.

Comment: so basically you are trying to say that computation of derivatives is not mandatory. One can go for coordinate descent with a precondition that there is a way to compute minima. Is this correct?

Comment: Yup, you just need a way to compute or approximate minima.